# How does SELECT FOR UPDATE behave with views in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, locking, transaction

To retrieve domain model data from PostgreSQL, I sometimes select against a view rather than a table. I do this so that I can return as much information as possible in one query, rather than fire off multiple queries to resolve all relational dependencies. Mostly this is because there is a 1-to-1 relationship between tables, or they are lookup tables and I just need certain columns, etc. To prevent certain race conditions, one strategy I'm using is `SELECT ... FOR SHARE/UPDATE` queries. I'm wondering how these behave when we start using them against views.

---

Suppose we have two tables `A` and `B`, each with a column `ID`. Now, suppose we have a view `AB` that is a join operation between those two tables. Let's assume this is a Cartesian join:

```
SELECT
    "A"."ID" AS "AID",
    "B"."ID" AS "BID"
FROM "A"
CROSS JOIN "B"
```

If we then `SELECT FOR UPDATE` against `AB` what rows of what tables will get locked in the following instances?

- `SELECT * FROM "AB" WHERE "AB"."AID" = :ID`
- `SELECT * FROM "AB" WHERE "AB"."BID" = :ID`
- `SELECT * FROM "AB" WHERE "AB"."AID" = :ID1 AND "AB"."BID" = :ID2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

The following rows will be locked for update in the three cases:

- a row with "ID" = :ID in table "A" and all rows in table "B"
- a row with "ID" = :ID in table "B" and all rows in table "A"
- a row with "ID" = :ID1 in table "A" and a row with "ID" = :ID2 in table "B"

The results are as one can expect after reading this statement in [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-for-update-share)

> If a locking clause is applied to a view or sub-query, it affects all tables used in the view or sub-query.

### How to test similar cases

Install the extension [pgrowlocks.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgrowlocks.html).

```
create extension if not exists pgrowlocks;
```

Run two instances of psql. In the first one start a transaction and execute a query.

**psql #1:**

```
begin;

select *
from "AB"
where "AID" = 3 and "BID" = 103
for update;
```

You can see locked rows in the other instance of psql.

**psql #2:**

```
select * from pgrowlocks('"B"');

 locked_row | locker | multi |  xids   |     modes      |  pids
------------+--------+-------+---------+----------------+--------
 (0,4)      |  88577 | f     | {88577} | {"For Update"} | {8068}
(1 row)
```

Do not forget to close the transaction at the end (before a next test).

**psql #1:**

```
rollback;
```

The first column of the above result is `ctid`. You can select the original row with the query:

```
select *
from "B"
where ctid = '(0,4)';
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and yes it's as I expected. I couldn't find that note in the documentation, I must have been looking in the wrong place. I guess it's time to look into a more robust locking strategy, starting with research into posts like this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81791/strategies-for-checking-out-records-for-processing

Comment: @e_i_pi: you could use [Advisory Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#advisory-locks) instead of "real" locks if all your code can be changed to comply with that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was thinking more along the lines of having locking tables that 1-to-1 with the main table, and locking that instead. I've used that technique before with good results, and since my app is DDD, this should work well with aggregate roots.